# Unzip script password

Tags: passwords, zip, archive

Ok here is my script

```
    #!/bin/bash
cd /var/backups/System/
unzip Themes.zip
exit 0
```

I need the script to put in the password automatically when unzipping the protected zip file which is the Themes.zip. Since the user don't know the password I need it to be enter through the script when extracting the zip archive. Hope this makes since?

Answer (score 14):

Use the `-P` flag for password. From `man unzip`:

```
-P password
              use  password to decrypt encrypted zipfile entries (if any).  THIS IS INSECURE!  Many multi-user operating systems provide ways for any user to see the current command line of any other user; even on stand-alone systems there is always the threat of over-the-shoulder peeking.  Storing the plaintext password as
              part of a command line in an automated script is even worse.  Whenever possible, use the non-echoing, interactive prompt to enter passwords.  (And where security is truly important, use strong encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively weak encryption provided by standard  zipfile  utili-
              ties.)
```

Comment: Like how would I write that script?

Comment: `unzip -P secretpassword Themes.zip`

Comment: If you don't want to hardcode it you could use something like [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/).

Comment: That's what I thought I did that but it's not doing anything it's not giving me what was zipped

Comment: Works for me. What do you mean it's not "giving you" what was zipped? Do you already have an unzipped version in the same directory? It may be asking you if you want to overwrite. Are you sure your zip file actually has anything in it? Make sure you used the `-r` flag if you zipped a directory.

Comment: Would i do this unzip -rp secretpassword Tones.zip or what?

Comment: No, you use the `-r` flag when you are zipping the directory. If you didn't then your .zip file is probably empty. Try this... `mkdir testing; echo "testing" > testing/testing.txt; zip -r -e testing.zip testing;`. Then put a password in twice and run your script on testing.zip.

Comment: what if the password contains special characters like `"()'$` ? How do I escape the password so the terminal doesn't try to interpret it as something else?

Comment: @DiegoDD wrap it in double quotes

Answer (score 3):

> unzip -P password Themes.zip

exit 0